# How do I post a file from Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a few different applications that require me to POST a file FROM Google App Engine to a remote site. I've tried a few approaches with urllib2, but I've run into problems with each approach as I have moved the code into GAE.

What is the simplest way to post a file (csv, zip, etc.) from Google App Engine to a remote website? Once I can post an existing file, I can move on to posting files from the datastore.

Comment: A file is just a container for bytes. There's really nothing special about files in this context; it's all a matter of how you encapsulate the data, which is sent using the `payload` argument as root documents.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at `urlfetch`. Example from [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview?hl=et).

```
import urllib

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

with open('/file', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
                        payload=data,
                        method=urlfetch.POST,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

Comment: Can you add a file to your example? Posting a file is the main objective.

Comment: This second code example looks to be for a post coming in to GAE rather than GAE code trying to post out to another website.

Comment: My bad sorry. I will try to post smth later when I have a chance to test.

Answer (score 0):

From the [reference](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction),

> `payload`: Body content for a `POST` or `PUT` request.

So just load the contents of the file and set the payload a la

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
  payload = fh.read()
response = urlfetch.fetch(url, payload=payload, method='POST')
```

and do what you would with `response`.

This would work in the exact same fashion with a string from a datastore object.

EDIT: `filename` will likely be a path relative to your project. So if your project lives in `/home/dinosaurs/sinclair` on your local machine and you have `/home/dinosaurs/sinclair/stuff/contents.xml` in your project, then your relative path that will work in production on App Engine is `stuff/contents.xml`.